# How works this expression for transform mac int48bits to hex? PYTHON

Tags: python, macos

Hello can anybody explain me how works this expression for transform a `getnode()` result in python to an hex standard format mac address?

```
import re, uuid
print ':'.join(re.findall('..', '%012x' % uuid.getnode()))
```

I cant understand what is the `%012x` and why transform the `getnode()`.

Please help  and thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `getnode()` function returns a 48-bit positive integer. It is then converted to hexadecimal format using [string formating](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting). The format breaks down as follows:

- `%` marks the start of the format specifier
- `0`  indicates zero-padding for numerical values
- `12` indicates the minimum field-width
- `x` specifies that the conversion type should be hexadecimal

So the result will be a string at least twelve characters long, zero-padded if necessary, and converted to hexadecimal format:

```
>>> u = uuid.getnode()
>>> mac = '%012x' % u
>>> u, mac, len(mac)
(127019754232, '001d92f7a2f8', 12)
```